# Tags are overlapping text in user profile "About Me"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

I'm using tags in my user profile "About Me" and I've noticed that the tag link is overlapping the "About Me" text like in the following example:

[image: profile]

**EDIT:** I've noted that the same happens when you use tags inside posts, which is a normal thing in meta, and when you are selecting a tag to create or edit a post.

Inside posts:

[image: posts]

Tag selection:

[image: tag selection]

Comment: All problems are related with the following CSS: `.post-tag { margin: 2px 15px 6px 0 }`. Changing it to `.post-tag { margin: 2px 7px 6px 7px }` would fix the issue.

Comment: This issue was fixed with the major design update: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/site-design-updates-are-live?cb=1